# CLR Procedure with XML parameter returns Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xml, c#, sql-clr

I have following CLR stored procedure, which is throwing error on this command

```
xmlDoc.LoadXml(inputXml);
```

code

```
    public static int spGetTaxOfficeXML(SqlXml _inputXml)
    {
        // this procedure rename Row elements name with NodeName attribute value
        string inputXml = _inputXml.ToString();
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(inputXml);

// procedure Logic

        SqlContext.Pipe.Send(inputXml);
        return 0;
    }
```

it works well, when the XML text is inside variable inside visual studio as a text. But when i upload code to the SQL server as CLR, and try to execute it from SQL Management Studio:

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = '<NodeA><NodeB></NodeB><NodeC AttributeX=""><Row NodeName="RowA" AttributeA="" AttributeB="abcd" AttributeC="efgh" /><Row NodeName="RowB" AttributeA="wxyz" /><Row NodeName="RowC" AttributeB="qwer" AttributeC="tyui" /><Row NodeName="RowD" AttributeA="stuv" AttributeB="erty" AttributeC="fghj" /></NodeC></NodeA>'

EXEC dbo.spGetTaxOfficeXML @XML
```

then this error is throwed:

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spGetTaxOfficeXML, Line 0
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "spGetTaxOfficeXML": 
System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
System.Xml.XmlException: 
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
   at StoredProcedures.spGetTaxOfficeXML(String inputXml)
```

I tried to solve the error with following code, because i though the utf8 byte could cause the error, but it did not help.

```
// if byte mark exception happens
    string _byteOrderMarkUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
    if (inputXml.StartsWith(_byteOrderMarkUtf8))
    {
        inputXml = inputXml.Remove(0, _byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length);
    }
```

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you made a bad assumption about what value is returned by the `SqlXml.ToString()` method, and then in testing in Visual Studio, you injected a value but did not check to see what `ToString()` was actually returning (which is: "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml"). Though you probably would have seen this had you placed the `SqlContext.Pipe.Send(inputXml);` line above the `xmlDoc.LoadXml(inputXml);` line ;-).

When working with the `Sql*` types, you want to almost always access them via the `Value` property, which they all have. The `Value` property does return the string version of the XML as you were wanting to get. However, this is less than ideal since you will be converted the XML to a string, only to convert that back to XML again when you call `XmlDocument.LoadXml()`.

A better way is to use the `SqlXml.CreateReader()` method which returns an `XmlReader`, and that can be used with the `XmlDocument.Load()` method.

I reworked your test code (below) to be an example showing all 3 of these variations:

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure()]
    public static int spGetTaxOfficeXML(SqlXml InputXml)
    {
        // this procedure rename Row elements name with NodeName attribute value
        XmlDocument _XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        _XmlDoc.Load(InputXml.CreateReader());

        // procedure Logic

        SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Incorrect:\n" + InputXml.ToString());

        SqlContext.Pipe.Send("\nBetter, but not an XmlDocument:\n" + InputXml.Value);

        SqlContext.Pipe.Send("\nCorrect:\n" + _XmlDoc.OuterXml);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Running the code above with the original test SQL returns the following in the "Messages" tab:

```
Incorrect:
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml

Better, but not an XmlDocument:
<NodeA><NodeB /><NodeC AttributeX=""><Row NodeName="RowA" AttributeA="" AttributeB="abcd" AttributeC="efgh" /><Row NodeName="RowB" AttributeA="wxyz" /><Row NodeName="RowC" AttributeB="qwer" AttributeC="tyui" /><Row NodeName="RowD" AttributeA="stuv" AttributeB="erty" AttributeC="fghj" /></NodeC></NodeA>

Correct:
<NodeA><NodeB /><NodeC AttributeX=""><Row NodeName="RowA" AttributeA="" AttributeB="abcd" AttributeC="efgh" /><Row NodeName="RowB" AttributeA="wxyz" /><Row NodeName="RowC" AttributeB="qwer" AttributeC="tyui" /><Row NodeName="RowD" AttributeA="stuv" AttributeB="erty" AttributeC="fghj" /></NodeC></NodeA>
```

P.S.  You don't need to worry about UTF-8, especially for NCHAR / NVARCHAR / XML data generated from within SQL Server, since SQL Server is UTF-16 LE.

Comment: It works ! Thank you for your explaining answer :-)